# WPF app crashes on startup

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013, crash

I did distribute WPF app to my customers. The app is built via visual studio 2013 pro on Windows 10. But he failed startup with CLR20r3 (related to presentationcore.dll).
I know that CLR20r3 error is occurred because of that some dll files do not exist on the PC. To resolve this problem. I have installed all of microsoft visual studio c++ redistributable packages and the latest .NET SDK to the PC. 
But I couldn't resolve it. 
What is the problem?

Comment: Have you try this http://www.personalcomputerfixes.com/general-errors/how-to-fix-clr20r3-error/ ?

Comment: In my situation, the app runs on all of software developer's PC. I think that this is not a problem related to the registry. I will try it anyway. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Check windows error log, maybe it could shed some light on what's missing. [fuslogvw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(v=vs.110).aspx) can be of help, but it's not so userfriendly.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't identify the missing DLL's, one option would be to copy all the DLL's referenced in Solution Explorer/YourProject/References into the same folder as your .exe, see if that fixes the issue. Then delete them 1 at a time until the issue arises again.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it. But it was not resolved. 
I also used microsoft blend 2013 for the UI, It's not referred on my question. is it can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple project with the same platform you've created your application. See whether that exe runs in the PC you need to run it. Then add dependencies one by one and check whether at what point it crashes.
Just a suggestion. May be it'll help you.